# OpenVPN - Can't connect when not local

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I followed [the help.ubuntu.com page on OpenVPN](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openvpn.html) to set up an OpenVPN server on my Ubuntu desktop.

I can connect to the server but only when I am on the same network that it is running on. I am using Viscosity on mac to connect. I am currently using my server's local IP address to connect. I have tried changing it to the public IP address, but when I do so, I can't connect to it at all, locally or from other networks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set up port forwarding on your router and connect by your public IP address. The process differs from router to router but you need to look through the settings for port forwarding, although some routers will also have different sections to make this process easier (my DLink router has a section called "Virtual Server") but the basics are, you need to forward the ports that openvpn is using (the defaults can be found [here](https://docs.openvpn.net/frequently-asked-questions/)) to the local IP address of the machine you want to openvpn into.

You'll then need to connect to the **public** ip, and your router will then *forward* that connection to the machine running the server (due to the fact you've told it to forward any connections to that port on to the local IP address of the server.

It's fairly simple once you find the settings in the router. If you've gone as far as getting the openvpn server working in the first place you should have no problems.